# translate curl cli to php curl

Tags: php, curl

When I'm using curl CLI it's working but when I'm using curl PHP it's not working :/

```
<?php
  exec('curl -X POST -H "Cookie: JSESSIONID='.$cookie.'" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d \'f1=value1&f2=value2&f3='. clean($content) .'\' http://localhost/loginAction.do');   
?>
```

But this one doesn't work..

```
<?php
  // Transcription CLI to cURL PHP
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST        => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
                    'f1'   => 'value1',
                    'f2'    => 'value2' ,
                    'f3' => $content
                ),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Cache-Control: no-cache',
                                'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                'Cookie: JSESSIONID='.$cookie
                        ),
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost/loginAction.do'
));

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

Does anyone can explain me why ?  I think I forgot nothing
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is php curl properly installed? Does it work for simpler cases? Do you get warnings/errors?

Comment: Yes, for example, I just try a GET from google.com and it works fine :)

Comment: Just an observation: you used `clean($content)` for cli access and just `$content` for API access.

Comment: @GáborBakos: Sorry to answer you only now. No I just do in my previous code : `$content=clean($content)`